# Unable to open Eclipse Oxygen editor

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-oxygen

Upon opening eclipse, I am greeted with the following error :

```
No editor descriptor for id org.eclipse.ui.internal.emptyEditorTab
```

[Snapshot of stack-trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lnpbf.png)

Kindly suggest any possible solutions. Do I need to uninstall/reinstall any plugins?

Comment: Make sure the Oxygen plugin is actually installed? Did you upgrade Eclipse without also reinstalling the plugin?

Comment: Does resetting the perspective solve the problem (_Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective...)?

Comment: @howlger Resetting the perspective doesn't work. I am specifically unable to open the java editor.

Comment: @JimGarrison Yup the oxygen plugin is installed. I am specificalle unable to access the Java editor.

Comment: @AbhishekRoy So the problem is caused by opening a Java file inside a Java project? You can close the editor that displays the exception, but on re-open, the same issue appears, right? Can you open the file with the text editor?

Comment: @howlger I can open the java file in all editors except the java editor.

Comment: @AbhishekRoy It looks like a problem with a third-party plug-in. Which Eclipse version do you use? Do you have the same problem with Eclipse Oxygen.1a without additional plug-ins?

Comment: @howlger I use Oxygen 1a. I installed Oracle Glassfish tools in order to add Glassfish 4 and since then the problem has been persistent.

Comment: @AbhishekRoy Does an update of [GlassFish Tools](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/glassfish-tools) help?